# Automatically Create Objects from Files in a Directory

Tags: r, automation, r-raster

I am trying to automate the data ingestion process in an R script that pulls data from a directory that updates regularly.

The general framework follows this process

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

f1.t1.cir <- stack("../raster/field1/f1_cir_t1.tif")
f1.t1.NDVI <- stack("../raster/field1/f1_ndvi_t1.tif")
f1.t1.RGB <- stack("../raster/field1/f1_ndvi_t1.tif")

f1.dat <- c(f1.t1.cir, f1.t1.NDVI, f1.t1.RGB)

for (i in f1.dat){
  plotRGB(i)
}
```

I would like to generate each `f1.t1.cir` type object from the directory directly such that when I add a new TIFF file `f1_cir_t2.tif`, the r script will create an object `f1.cir.t2`.

I am trying to use something like

```
a <- list.files(path= "../raster/field1", pattern = "\\.tif$")
b <- gsub("_", "\\.", a)

for (i in a) {
  assign(get(b[(which(a==i))]), stack((paste("../raster/field1/", i,sep=""))))
}
```

At this point, I would have all tiff files as stacked multiband raster objects in the R workspace.

I am getting the following error,

`Error in get(b[(which(a == i))]) : object 'f1_t1_DSM.tif' not found`

I can not figure out if this is a get() problem, or something else.

for reference

```
> a
[1] "f1_t1_DSM.tif"  "f1_t1_NDVI.tif"

> b
[1] "f1.t1.DSM.tif"  "f1.t1.NDVI.tif"
```

so that much is working, I think.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Forget `assign` and `get`; create a single list object and put the cir, NDVI and RGB objects in that one list. The list can be _named_ so you can refer to each programmatically. Much better than haphazardly dumping them in your workspace.

Comment: @joran, that sounds like a great way to go... can you provide an example? How can I create the list of objects based on the contents of the folder? -thx

Answer (score 1):

@joran, great suggestion...

```
f1.t1<-list()

for(i in list.files(path= "../raster/field1", pattern = "\\.tif$")){
  f1.t1[[i]]<-stack((paste("../raster/field1/", i, sep="")))
}
```

Worked very well, no need to change the names.

Thank you.

Comment: This whole code can be written in two, much simpler, lines: `files = list.files('../raster/field1', pattern = '\\.tif$'); f1.t1 = lapply(paste0('../raster/field1/', files), stack)`